# Should I use a colon here?

Tags: meaning, grammar

> I also encouraged her to tell the bullies: "Get a life."

Should there be a colon here or nothing?

Comment: Using 'tell' as a quotative verb (ie with direct speech) sounds odd to my British ears. [CD](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/say-or-tell) has: 'We [often] use _say_ with direct speech. We don’t normally use _tell_ in this way.' I'm prepared to believe that it's not so unusual in the US. But the use of a pre-quote  comma would seem a throwback here to me; neither the colon nor zero punctuation affects the size of the jolt the use of _tell_ gives me.

Comment: I think tell introducing a quotation would be common in academic writing: *Shakespeare tells us "..."* but in such contexts the colon is definitely optional.

Comment: Tell seems fine here, because it relates to passing on a message rather than reporting verbating speech. "Can you tell your father to take out the trash"/"Tell your father: take out the trash." Whether it should be punctuated like speech or not is less clear, but a colon seems fine whether introducing a quotation or reporting speech.

Comment: A colon is not needed at all. Colons generally stand for a word that adds heaviness to a sentence.

Answer (score 1):

As a standalone sentence perhaps it won't make much of a difference whether to use or forgo a colon (or a dash, for that matter). However, I would suggest dropping the colon if the sentence forms a part of some story: the colon doesn't really do much there other than interrupt the flow.